# Getting undefined object in redux state

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm calling an api that returns a bunch of objects and then dispatching the response.

When i looked on to redux devtool, the object is correctly dispatched, but in state it stores as `"undefined[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],........,"`.

API format:

```
0: {id: 188, category_id: 23, en_name: "The Local", en_description: "Lorem Ipsum", price: 12, …}
1: {id: 212, category_id: 25, en_name: "Protein", en_description: "Lorem Ipsum", price: 5, …}
2: {id: 205, category_id: 24, en_name: "House Buttermilk Biscuits and Gravy", en_description: "Lorem Ipsum", price: 10, …}
3: {id: 206, category_id: 24, en_name: "Griddle me this Pancakes", en_description: "Lorem Ipsum", price: 10, …}
```

Redux devtool shown dispatch is also same as the above api.

while checking the state with redux devtool,

`"undefined[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],........,"`

Code :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://theapi.com/something/something"
      );
      let { categories, menus } = response.data;

      setCategories(categories);
      dispatch(setItemToCart(menus));
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Reducers and action :

```
const initialState = {
  items: [],
};

export const addItems = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setItemToCart(state, action) {
      state.items = state.item + action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setItemToCart } = addItems.actions;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reducer should be implemented as

```
state.items = [...state.items, action.payload];
```